# Why does the code execute multiple times when I pass a parameter to the controller in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

I'm having a strange problem with passing a parameter from View to Controller.

Program.cs

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
name: "default",
pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

View

```
<a class="quickview" asp-controller="Product" asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@product.Alias">
```

Controller

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Details(string id)
{
    var result = await _mediator.Send(new GetProductViewModelQuery(id));

    return View(result);
 }
```

This parameter is correctly passed to the controller and the Details view is returned with the product, but when the view is loading, the flow again goes to the controller with a null id and finally an empty model is returned.
Strange situation, because it only works correctly when I pass asp-route-id = "@ product.ProductId" (Guid) and with other parameters the action is called several times ...

Comment: You have java script written on the view to call the action ajax way?

Comment: Yes, it's through fotorama.js script but I can't find the exact code cause yet